# How to convert this viml autocommand into .lua config for neovim?

Tags: lua, neovim, coc.nvim, nvim-lspconfig

```
au FileType python let b:coc_root_patterns = ['.git', '.env', 'venv', '.venv', 'setup.cfg', 'setup.py', 'pyrightconfig.json']
```

I guess not many people using this config with neovim.

Comment: i did not find an answer to this. as a workaround i'm using `vim.cmd(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

See:
:help nvim_command
Than you can do...

```
local vscript = "au FileType python let b:coc_root_patterns = ['.git', '.env', 'venv', '.venv', 'setup.cfg', 'setup.py', 'pyrightconfig.json']"

vim.api.nvim_command(vscript)
```

Check afterwards in nvim command mode: `:au FileType`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nvim 0.7 or later, there is now native Lua api [`nvim_create_autocmd`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_create_autocmd()) for this.

```lua
local api = vim.api

api.nvim_create_autocmd({'FileType'},
  pattern = 'python',
  callback = function()
    vim.b.coc_root_patterns = {'.git', '.env', 'venv', '.venv', 'setup.cfg', 'setup.py', 'pyrightconfig.json'}
  end
)
```

The equivalent for vim script `b:xxx` variable is `vim.b` in Lua, see also `:help vim.b` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this.

```lua
local group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('coc_root', { clear = true })
local events = { 'FileType' }
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd( events, {
  pattern = 'python',
  callback = function()
    vim.bo.coc_root_patterns = { '.git', '.env', 'venv', '.venv', 'setup.cfg', 'setup.py', 'pyrightconfig.json' }
  end,
  group = group,
})
```

I really did not test it, let me know if it does not work.

[vim.bo](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.bo), [autocmd](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#api-autocmd)